# How to change sequence of old array according to new array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a existing array, and now I want to change the sequence of old array according to new array's key

```
// Existing Array
var data = [
    {
        name: 'section-intro', 
        children: ['service-addressBox', 'service-banner']
    },
    {name: 'section-breadcrumb', children: ['h', 'i', 'j']},
    {name: 'section-products', children: []},
    {name: 'section-about', children: []},
    {name: 'section-timeline', children: []},
    {name: 'section-nearbyOutlets', children: []}
]


// New Array
['section-nearbyOutlets', 'section-intro', 'section-products', 'section-breadcrumb', 'section-timeline', 'section-about']
```

Comment: If I understand correctly, the existing array should be ordered according to the order in the new array? What have you tried to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

If the two arrays have the same number of elements (or if you only are interested in the elements appearing in the new one) you can try something like this using `map`:

```js
// Existing Array
const data = [
  {
    name: 'section-intro',
    children: ['service-addressBox', 'service-banner']
  },
  { name: 'section-breadcrumb', children: ['h', 'i', 'j'] },
  { name: 'section-products', children: [] },
  { name: 'section-about', children: [] },
  { name: 'section-timeline', children: [] },
  { name: 'section-nearbyOutlets', children: [] }
]

// New Array
const newArray = ['section-nearbyOutlets', 'section-intro', 'section-products', 'section-breadcrumb', 'section-timeline', 'section-about']

const orderedArray = newArray.map(element => data.find(originalElement => originalElement.name === element))

console.log(JSON.stringify(orderedArray, null, 2))
```

Here we create a new array (`orderedArray`) but you can also overwrite one of the existing two if you prefer to.

Answer (score 0):

If we're talking about ordering, than you can use [`Array.sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)

```js
// Existing Array
let data = [
    {
        name: 'section-intro', 
        children: ['service-addressBox', 'service-banner']
    },
    {name: 'section-breadcrumb', children: ['h', 'i', 'j']},
    {name: 'section-products', children: []},
    {name: 'section-about', children: []},
    {name: 'section-timeline', children: []},
    {name: 'section-nearbyOutlets', children: []}
]
// New Array
const order = ['section-nearbyOutlets', 'section-intro',
  'section-products', 'section-breadcrumb', 'section-timeline', 'section-about']

data = data.sort((a, b) => {
  const ixa = order.indexOf(a.name)
  const ixb = order.indexOf(b.name)
  return ixa < ixb ? -1 : 1
})

console.log(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish by manually sorting by name

```
var temp=[]
for(let name :newarray){
   for(let datum:data){
     if(datum.name==name)
       temp.append(datum)
     }
   }
data=temp
```